# Ctrl + C copy webpage text - copy extra data to clipboard

Tags: javascript, web

I've just been browsing some recipes to try this weekend and copied some text from this webpage and pasted into Word.

http://www.lovepotatoes.co.uk/recipes/baked-potatoes-top-25/jacket-potato-smoked-mackerel-and-spring-onion

when I paste it however, additional data is there ("See more at [url]").
This does not happen when visiting the site with Firefox and NoScript enabled, so I'm assuming it is in Javascript. How is this being done?

Comment: Javascript is waiting for an event of `onCopy()`, when this happens it appends some text to whatever you have copied.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I didn't know there was an onCopy() event in Javascript - if I had then I could have guessed what was happening.

Comment: Yes people taking website content is bad, but appending some text via Javascript is not going to prevent it from happening and simply irritates legitimate users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick Google search result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more at: <a href='"+document.location.href+"'>"+document.location.href+"</a><br />Copyright &copy; c.bavota"; // change this if you want
    var copytext = selection + pagelink;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position='absolute';
    newdiv.style.left='-99999px';
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>
```

As you can see, it binds on oncopy event.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I wasn't aware that there was an oncopy event in Javascript (never had to use it before).

Comment: Was wondering how they did it. I was looking for a way to defeat it, but it doesn't bug me that much.